# Unable to convert all css and js features to WP theme

Tags: theme-development

I am trying to convert a HTML and CSS template that uses `.js` files as well, into a WP theme on my localhost. The `index.html` has the following:

```
<head>
<title>Home</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<link rel="icon" href="img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
<meta name="description" content="Your description">
<meta name="keywords" content="Your keywords">
<meta name="author" content="Your name">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/responsive.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/camera.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/touchTouch.css">
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-migrate-1.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="js/superfish.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobilemenu.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script src="js/camera.js"></script>
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!-->
<script src="js/jquery.mobile.customized.min.js"></script>
<!--<![endif]-->
<script src="js/jquery.equalheights.js"></script>
<script src="js/touchTouch.jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.carouFredSel-6.1.0-packed.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.touchSwipe.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/sForm.js"></script>
```

For this I have written the following in header.php:

```
<head>
<!--<?php bloginfo('name'); ?> <?php wp_title(); ?></title> -->
<title>Home</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<link rel="icon" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
<meta name="description" content="Your description">
<meta name="keywords" content="Your keywords">
<meta name="author" content="Your name">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/bootstrap.css" type="text/css"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/camera.css" type="text/css"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/responsive.css" type="text/css"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/touchTouch.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>" type="text/css">
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/jquery.js"></script>
<!--<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/jquery1.js"></script>-->
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/jquery-migrate-1.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/superfish.js"></script>
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/jquery.mobilemenu.js"></script>
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/camera.js"></script>
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!-->
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/jquery.mobile.customized.min.js"></script>
<!--<![endif]-->
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/jquery.equalheights.js"></script>
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/touchTouch.jquery.js"></script>
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/jquery.carouFredSel-6.1.0-packed.js"></script>
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/jquery.touchSwipe.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/sForm.js"></script>
```

All the `CSS` and `.js` files are therefore linked. But yet some minor CSS and probably some js features are not being converted. Also the WP dashboard toolbar isn't appearing. once I visit the site from the dashboard, I have to click the back button of the browser to go to the WP dashboard. I have been suggested to use the the `wp_head()` and `wp_footer()` functions but after reading from codex.wordpress.org, can't figure out how to use them. 
Also the HTML for the menu bar is as follows:

About Us

Artists

Works

- Dolore ipsu
  Consecte
  - Dolore ipsu
  - Consecte
  - Elit Conseq
- Elit Conseq

Blog

Contacts

I have written `functions.php` as:

```
<?php
function register_my_menus() {
  register_nav_menus(
    array(
      'header-menu' => __( 'Header Menu' ),
      'extra-menu' => __( 'Extra Menu' )
    )
  );
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menus' );
?>
```

and written the following in my `header.php`:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'header-menu', 'container_class' => 'nav-collapse nav-collapse_ collapse',  'menu_class' => 'nav sf-menu clearfix')); ?>
```

But the WP menu is displaying as a vertical list. I want it to be horizontal with the CSS as in the HTML template.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer changing all:
`<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>` and `<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>`
into:

```
<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>
```

For connection to default `style.css` I prefer to change:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>" type="text/css">
```

into:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php bloginfo( 'stylesheet_url' ); ?>" />
```

I found no script type is defined in any of the scripts:

```
<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The best option of using `wp_head()` is using it just before the closing  tag, like:

```
...
<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
```

And the best way to using `wp_footer()` is using it in footer, but just before the closing `</body>` tag:

```
...
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
</body>
```

And beside that,
[Ian Stewart's theme development tutorial](http://themeshaper.com/2009/06/22/wordpress-themes-templates-tutorial/) may help you understand the very core things of WordPress themes in a very easy way.

And also, WordPress by default uses some `js` files, so `js` can conflict with those in many ways. If, then you have to find out the conflicting `js` manually.

And for a menu CSS, I call **[THIS ONE](http://pastebin.com/uiNKx7LM)** a Universal Menu CSS. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should enqueue your js and CSS this way :

```
  function wpse_105303_enqueue_my_scripts() {

    wp_register_script( 'my-js1', get_stylesheet_directory_uri(). '/js/myjs1.js',false,null,true );
    wp_register_style( 'my-style1',  get_stylesheet_directory_uri(). '/css/my-style1.css' );

    wp_enqueue_script('my-js1');
    wp_enqueue_style('my-style1');
     }
   add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','wpse_105303_enqueue_my_scripts');
```

The code goes in the file called `functions.php`

Comment: Thank you for the reply. So if I have 10 css files and 14 js files to enqueue do I have to write a separate wp_register_script() and wp_register_style() entry for each of those files? And also their corresponding register_script() and register_style() entries separately? And in which file and where should I write this code ?

Comment: I've edited code (made a mystake). No you do not have to, you can use `wp_enqueue_script` and `wp_enqueue_style` directly like `wp_enqueue_style( 'my-style1',  get_stylesheet_directory_uri(). '/css/my-style1.css' );` but yes you have to do this for each file. The code goes in `functions.php` as I've said in answer.

Comment: Thank you once again for your reply. After including this code in the functions.php, where I already have a function written for my menus and an add_action tag for it, is it required to add another add_action tag for the new function? Also how should I write the action tag?
My present functions.php has the following:
<?php
function register_my_menus() {
  register_nav_menus(
    array(
      'header-menu' => __( 'Header Menu' ),
      'extra-menu' => __( 'Extra Menu' )
    )
  );
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menus' );
?>

Comment: function I've written is only for JS and CSS (apart from the main stylesheet which has to be left in header.php).

Comment: I've added the following to the existing functions.php code:

function demoweb_enqueue_my_scripts() {

    wp_register_script( 'my-js1', get_stylesheet_directory_uri(). '/js/myjs1.js',false,null,true ); // for each file
    wp_register_style( 'my-style1',  get_stylesheet_directory_uri(). '/css/my-style1.css' ); // for each file

    }
   add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','demoweb_enqueue_my_scripts'); add_action('wp_enqueue_styles','demoweb_enqueue_my_scripts');
   
But the problem is still there. Kindly advise.

Regards

Debashis